# Django DRF rename field in serializer but unique_together validation fails

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

In the serializer used to create a model I want to rename my model field to (field_name)_id so it's clearer for API consumers that this field is an ID field. The model also has a `unique_together` constraint on some fields. However when validation runs in the serializer, it fails with a KeyError that the field does not exist:

```
...rest_framework/utils/serializer_helpers.py", line 148, in __getitem__
    return self.fields[key]
KeyError: 'question'
```

Is there a simple way to get this to work? Minimal example code below.

**Model**

```
class MyModel(Model):
            question = ForeignKey('uppley.Question', null=False, on_delete=PROTECT)
            user = ForeignKey('catalystlab.User', null=False, on_delete=PROTECT)

            class Meta:
                unique_together = ('question', 'user',)
```

**Serializer**

```
        class MyCreateSerializer(ModelSerializer):

            question_id = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
                write_only=True,
                source='question',
                queryset=Question.objects.all(),
            )

            user_id = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
                write_only=True,
                source='user',
                queryset=User.objects.all(),
            )

            class Meta:
                model = MyModel
                fields = ('question_id', 'user_id',)
```

**test.py - test for demonstration purposes**

```
        question = QuestionFactory()
        user = UserFactory()

        data = {
            'question_id': question.id,
            'user_id': user.id,
        }
        serializer = MyCreateSerializer(data=data, write_only=True)
        is_valid = serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True) #KeyError exception raised here.
```

Previously with DRF 3.10.3 this all worked fine, however with 3.11.0 this now throws a KeyError as mentioned above.

**What I have tried**

Removing the `source` field on `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` for `user_id` and `question_id` in the Serializer actually results in bypassing the unique_together validation in DRF and the KeyError is avoided. However the validated data is not mapped back to the original field names (`user` and `question`). In this case we have to manually change the keys back to their original names before we can create an instance of the Model from the validated data.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can make a custom serializer like :-

```
class MyCreateSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

    question_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
         write_only=True,
         queryset=Question.objects.all(),
    )

    user_id = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
         write_only=True,
         queryset=User.objects.all(),
    )
```

and make custom create function in it for creating object. like :-

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    try:
        question = validated_data.get('question_id')
        user = validated_data.get('user_id')
        instance = MyModel.objects.create(question=question, user=user)
    except TypeError:
        raise TypeError("Something went wrong while creating objects")

    return instance
```